Is the Python Mariadb connector module capable of using prepared statements?
I'm confused about this. By "prepared statement", I mean an object which is delivered by going something like
prep_stmt = cursor.prepared_statement("INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) VALUES (%1 %2)")

... and where you then use that object multiple times, inserting the values and executing by going something like
prep_stmt.set("mike", "rodent")
prep_stmt.execute()

or maybe
prep_stmt.set(1, "mike")
prep_stmt.set(2, "rodent")
cursor.execute(prep_stmt)

On this page of the MariaDB manual I see much evidence of this existing in MariaDB's SQL language.
However, wherever I see the MariaDB Python module being explained, this is said to be the kind of statement understood by "prepared statement":
cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE sale_date >= ? and price > ?", (sale_date_val, price_val)) 

An example from 2014 can be found here, where the context is not MariaDB but mysqldb. In the comments, newtover says this is not a true prepared statement, but Alex Martelli then says yet it is, before conceding that it probably isn't. And in the last comment, Olaf Dietsche says he has examined the source code and finds that nothing here is involved beyond string formatting.
I imagine that any string formatting mechanism in MariaDB's Python module is probably a little more sophisticated than normal, because there are certain characters (e.g. empty space) would be difficult to just slot into a "?" in a pseuo-prepared-statement.
However, I'm just wondering whether, when coding in Python, there is in fact a way to use genuine prepared statements, which as I say clearly exist in MariaDB SQL...

The SQL prepared statements can only be used in stored procedures. So you can't use them directly in queries from Python.

@Barmar OK thanks for that clarification

@Barmar not true.  https://dbfiddle.uk/uSZ9BS8b (and https://dbfiddle.uk/HfOB4jH- !) but PREPARE isn't really relevant to this question

TIL they relaxed the requirement that EXECUTE parameters come from user variables, which makes it at least possible to use for this, but not a good idea

Prepared statements can be server-side or client-side.  Both are used the same way in your code, calling a prepare method and then setting the bind parameters and executing.  In the client-side ones the client library interpolates the bind parameter values, doing any needed quoting, and then executes the resulting statement.  In server-side ones, the interpolation is done by the server.
I believe most client libraries use client-side prepared statements; the perl library and perhaps some others allow you to chose.
Typically you don't care which is being used.
The PREPARE statement is a different thing, used for dynamic sql where your sql code itself needs to assemble an sql statement, rather than receiving it from a client.  Though in principle you could use PREPARE/EXECUTE statements to force interpolation to be done server-side.

Thanks, but this is beyond my level of understanding. Surely if you can/could prepare an object this must shave some time off, compared to writing and then the code interpolating a string of some kind.

Also, as I hope I made clear, this is specific to a Python context. Your linked dbfiddles don't seem to be relevant to someone using the Mariadb Python module (although I'd love to be shown to be wrong about that).

time taken to interpolate is trivial, not worth worrying about.   I don't see anything about the python library (is there just one?) and what exactly it does.

I was not thinking of the time taken to interpolate a string ... but that command, execute, must involve passing that command on to the SQL engine. I'm really just comparing to PHP, which I haven't used for some time. I don't remember the backend RDBMS (might have been MySQL) but I do remember you could prepare a statement and then inject parameters ... so you could re-use these (possibly genuine) prepared statements. (Although I just checked, and it seems the mysqli module's prepared statements might just be about preventing SQL injection attacks...)

The main difference between the two methods is how many times the server has to parse the SQL if you execute the query multiple times with different parameters. Using server-side prepares only parses once. But unless the query is very large, this is probably negligible.

and if nobody before you worried about it with the python connector, you can presume you shouldn't either
